# panda's dataframe isn't working in my code

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to scrape twitter data for my thesis work. But in this below's code, dataframe isn't working. I mean, dataframe isn't showing at the output line. How can I modify this code to build my dataframe? Another problem is that I want to scrape data by filtering location. How can I do this?

```
import tweepy
import re
import pandas as pd
import itertools
import collections
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from textblob import TextBlob
import os

consumer_key = ""
consumer_secret = ""
access_token = ""
access_token_secret = ""
    
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth,wait_on_rate_limit=True,wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True)

latitude =  56.130367   # geographical centre of search
longitude =  -106.346771    # geographical centre of search
max_range =  1 

tweets = tweepy.Cursor(api.search,
                       q="Shopify" + " -filter:retweets",
                       #geocode = "%f,%f,%dkm" % (latitude,longitude,max_range),
                       lang="en",
                       since="2020-01-01").items(10)

for tweet in tweets:
    print(tweet.text)
    analysis = TextBlob(tweet.text)
    print('Date=', tweet.created_at,'Location=', tweet.user.location)
    print(analysis.sentiment)
    

    if analysis.sentiment[0] > 0:
        print('Positive')
    elif analysis.sentiment[0] < 0:
        print('Negative')
    else:
        print('Neutral')

    print('====================================================================')
    print()


user_data = [[tweet.created_at, remove_characters(tweet.user.name), tweet.user.location,
              remove_characters(tweet.text), TextBlob(tweet.text).sentiment[0],
              'Positive' if TextBlob(tweet.text).sentiment[0] > 0 
              else 'Negative' if TextBlob(tweet.text).sentiment[0] < 0
              else 'Nuetral'] 
              for tweet in tweets]

    
tweet_df = pd.DataFrame(data=user_data,
                        columns=['Created At', "User", 'Location', 'Text', 'Sentiment', 'Polarity', 'favorite_count'])
    

tweet_df.head(10)
```

Comment: Hey @rabby26, you need to be a little more clear about what your problem is. What "*isn't working*"? You also mention "*Mean dataframe*", but that doesn't appear in the code you have provided.

Comment: Hi brother, It supposed to be an understanding problem. btw, I have edited this line. Thank you...